# Laravel translation strings

Tags: laravel, laravel-translatable

I translated Laravel manually, but after the translation these codes from the picture appeared. How can I handle the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOJ27.png)

I tried to find these codes in the translation file but couldn't find them. I expect the problem to be fixed.

Comment: do: `php artisan optimize` to clear configs/cache..

Comment: Where did you put your translation, depending on Laravel version, it could be at the project root or in ressources

Answer (score 2):

If you want to translate the text string "Welcome" to Spanish, you can create a "***/lang/es/messages.php***" file containing:

```
<?php

return [
    'welcome' => 'Bienvenido',
];
```

Then, in your Blade view, you can use the built-in translation function in Laravel to retrieve the translated string:

```
echo __('messages.welcome');
```

Laravel will automatically retrieve the appropriate text string for the currently selected language in your application. If the current language is Spanish, Laravel will display "Bienvenido" instead of "Welcome".

---

For your case, for the English language you have a default file "***lang/en/default_lang.php***" and for the Spanish language you got "***lang/es/default_lang.php***" with following content.

```
<?php

// lang/en/default_lang.php
return [
    'invoice_overview' => 'Invoices',
    'all_tasks_overview' => 'All tasks',
];

// lang/es/default_lang.php
return [
    'invoice_overview' => 'Facturas',
    'all_tasks_overview' => 'Todas las tareas',
];
```

You can use it in your application using the `@lang` blade directive or `__()` helper in your views, controllers or mails for example.

Check the official Laravel documentation for more details [about localization](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization).